# Onprepare with jasmine-reporters causes failures while executing with IE

Tags: jasmine, protractor

After some time trying to figure out why the beginning of my tests fails (only for IE, with chrome works just fine), I found out that it is caused by the on-prepare function when comes to this part of the code:

```
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specDone: function (result) {
      browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) 
      {
        var browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
          var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./execution_results/reports/results/screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName+ '.png');
          stream.write(new Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
          stream.end();
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

If i comment this part, the tests goes smoothly.
My login page is not Angular, so I turn off the sync for the login and turn on again, not sure if this could be related.

How can I force protractor to wait for this part to finish before continuing with the run?

I already tried to add this code in a promise (in conf file) to make protractor wait but even with this i get the jasmine timeout 'TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 20000ms', so I believe I did it wrong.

The error I get is:

```
Failed: Unable to determine type from: E. Last 1 characters read: E
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Full conf file:

```
var jasmineReporters = require('./lib/node_modules/jasmine-reporters');
var HTMLReport = require('./lib/node_modules/protractor-html-reporter-2');
var mkdirp = require('./lib/node_modules/mkdirp');
var fs = require('./lib/node_modules/fs-extra');
let date = require('./lib/node_modules/date-and-time');  

var environmentToExecute = 'https://myportal' 

exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://'+process.env.AUTOTEST_ADDRESS+'/wd/hub',

framework: 'jasmine2',

specs: ['all my specs'],

suites: {
  //All my suites
},

allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

onPrepare: function () {   
  {
   //Here I create the folders (removed to make it shorter)
  }

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: './execution_results/reports/xml/',
    filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
  }));

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specDone: function (result) {
      browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) 
      {
        var browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
          var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./execution_results/reports/results/screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName+ '.png');
          stream.write(new Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
          stream.end();
        });
      });
    }
  });
},

//HTMLReport called once tests are finished
onComplete: function() 
{
  //I removed this to make it shorter, but basically it is the function
  // that comverts the xml in html and build the report
},

jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  // If true, display spec names.
  isVerbose: true,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
},

params: {
    //Other files like functions and so on...
  },
  login:{
    //parameters to login
  }
},

multiCapabilities:
[
 {
   'browserName': 'internet explorer',
   'version': 11,
 },
 /*   
 //chrome, firefox...
 */
],

};//end of Conf.js
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had issues with asynchronous actions in a Jasmine reporter recently and unfortunately could not figure out how to get them to await promise results properly before moving on. If anyone else has information on this I would greatly appreciate it also.

I did implement a work around using global variables and the AfterAll hook which is able to correctly await promises which may work for you.
I'm assuming that you only need the 'fullname' property of your result so you can try this.

Declare a global properties in your onPrepare and you can assigned this global variable values in your reporter. Assign it the spec fullname value inside of **specStarted** instead of **specDone**. Then you can create you screenshot inside you tests afterAll statements which are correctly able to await promise results.

```
onPrepare: function () {   
   global.currentlyExecutingSpec = 'tbd';

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specStarted: function (result) {
      currentlyExecutingSpec = result.fullName
    }
  })
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: './execution_results/reports/xml/',
    filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
  }));
}
```

**Inside your testFiles**

```
afterEach(function(){
  browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) 
  {
      var browserName = caps.get('browserName');
      browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
        var stream = 
        fs.createWriteStream('./execution_results/reports/results/screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + currentlyExecutingSpec + '.png');
        stream.write(new Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
        stream.end();
      });
  };
});
```

Comment: Hi! thank you very much.. this worked! just had to change from AfterAll to afterEach in order to get one screenshot per 'It', thanks for the help